# apache redirectmatch capture groups not injecting to destination properly

Tags: redirect, apache2, url

I'm trying to redirect requests to my old git server (with my old username) to the new server (with my new username).

I'm trying to set up the following conditions:

1. If url is of the form http(s)://git.glmdev.tech/glmdev/any/url/here, redirect it to https://git.garrettmills.dev/garrettmills/any/url/here.
2. If url is http(s)://git.glmdev.tech/glmdev, redirect to https://git.glmdev.tech/garrettmills
3. Otherwise, redirect any http(s)://git.glmdev.tech/any/other/url to https://git.garrettmills.dev/any/other/url

I'm trying to use Apache2's RedirectMatch to do this using capture groups. I have the following virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.glmdev.tech
    RedirectMatch 301 /glmdev/(.*) https://git.garrettmills.dev/garrettmills/$1
    Redirect /glmdev/ https://git.garrettmills.dev/garrettmills/
    Redirect / https://git.garrettmills.dev/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName git.glmdev.tech
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/glmdev/ssl/_star/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/glmdev/ssl/_star/cert.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/glmdev/ssl/_star/ca.crt
    RedirectMatch 301 /glmdev/(.*) https://git.garrettmills.dev/garrettmills/$1
    Redirect /glmdev/ https://git.garrettmills.dev/garrettmills/
    Redirect / https://git.garrettmills.dev/
</VirtualHost>
```

Conditions 2 and 3 work as expected, however navigating to some http(s)://git.glmdev.tech/glmdev/repositoryname redirects to https://git.garrettmills.dev/garrettmills

Not sure why the capture group isn't being found or appended to the URL. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.